# Does UINavigationItem -title provide accessibility features?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, accessibility

I am trying to provide VoiceOver users with slightly different versions of my `UINavigationItem` titles. The displayed titles don't quite work for the visual impaired due to abbreviations that get mangled by the text to speech engine.

Is there any way to add accessibility hinting to these titles in form of a `accessibilityLabel`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it appears the only way to add an `accessibilityLabel` to a `UINavigationItem` is by creating a custom `UILabel` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    label.text = @"Human readable string incl. abbreviations";
    label.accessibilityLabel = @"VoiceOver friendly text";
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:label];
    [label sizeToFit];
    [label release];
}
```

Comment: At least with iOS 8, you can set the accessibilityLabel on the navigationItem itself and that seems to work.